# Action of JSF h:commandButton not invoked after setting disabled=true in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf, commandbutton, disabled-control

Who can explain the following behaviour? When disabling a command button in JavaScript, the action method is never executed.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="test" action="#{bean.test}" onclick="disabled=true" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: try with `action="#{bean.test}"`

Comment: You can't disable the button *before* the action occurs. JSF will check if the button is disabled, and will not fire the action.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks! You might be adding this as an answer as probably this is the correct answer to my question...

Comment: @membersound BalusC answer is correct, mine is wrong. Please accept his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a HTML form element is disabled, then its `name=value` pair won't be sent as HTTP request parameter and hence JSF will never find it in the request parameter map. For command buttons this in turn means that the action is never invoked.

You need to disable the button shortly *after* the form has been submitted. The proposed suggestions to use `disabled` attribute make no sense as it's too late. It's not set during submitting the form, but it's only set when the response returns.

To achieve your particular functional requirement in *this particular* case, you could use JS to timeout the disablement.

```html
<h:commandButton ... onclick="setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'' + this.id + '\').disabled=true;', 50);" />
```

Much better is however to use `<f:ajax onevent>`

#### See also:

- [Pure Java/JSF implementation for double submit prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285530/pure-java-jsf-implementation-for-double-submit-prevention)
- [Reload parts of a page before action is executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744614/reload-parts-of-a-page-before-action-is-executed/12744647#12744647)

Answer (score -1):

Try to disable the button from the BackBean using the property "disabled" of the component

```
disabled="#{!(bean.disable)}"
```

This option will work when the component is rendered, after the information sent